# passing mvp matix to opengl android

Tags: android, opengl-es, shader

I'm having mpvMatrix (mvpMatrix is calculated as model * view * projection using `Matrix.multiply()`) and passing it to shader and it's ok.

Now i'd like to move multiplication from CPU to GPU (from `Matrix.multiply` to shader).

If i'm trying to pass model, view and projection martrix separately and multiply them in shader i see nothing.

I'm sure matrix are not null and have real values (as if i multiply them on CPU instead of GPU it's ok), matrix uniform index are >= 0 (they are found in shader). What can be wrong?

Shaders:

```
private final String vertexShader =
              "uniform mat4 u_mMatrix;      \n"       // Матрица модели
            + "uniform mat4 u_vMatrix;      \n"       // Матрица модели
            + "uniform mat4 u_pMatrix;      \n"        // Матрица модели

            + "attribute vec4 a_Position;     \n"     // Информация о положении вершин.

            + "attribute vec2 a_TexCoordinate; \n"    // Per-vertex texture coordinate information we will pass in.
            + "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;   \n"    // This will be passed into the fragment shader.

            + "void main()                    \n"     // Начало программы вершинного шейдера.
            + "{                              \n"
            + "   v_TexCoordinate = a_TexCoordinate; \n"
            + "   mat4 mvMatrix = u_mMatrix * u_vMatrix;"
            + "   mat4 mvpMatrix = mvMatrix * u_pMatrix;"
            + "   gl_Position =  mvpMatrix  \n"     // gl_Position специальные переменные используемые для хранения конечного положения.
            + "               * a_Position;   \n"     // Умножаем вершины на матрицу для получения конечного положения
            + "}                              \n";    // в нормированных координатах экрана.

    private final String fragmentShader =
            "precision mediump float;         \n"     // Устанавливаем по умолчанию среднюю точность для переменных. Максимальная точность в фрагментном шейдере не нужна.
            + "uniform sampler2D u_Texture;   \n"     // The input texture.
            + "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;  \n"     // Interpolated texture coordinate per fragment.
            + "void main()                    \n"     // Точка входа для фрагментного шейдера.
            + "{                              \n"
            + "   gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_Texture, v_TexCoordinate);  \n"     // Передаем значения цветов.
            + "}";
```

Binding:

```
    mMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "u_mMatrix"); // = 0
    vMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "u_vMatrix"); // = 2
    pMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(programHandle, "u_pMatrix"); // = 3
```

Drawing:

```
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(mMatrixHandle, 1, false, modelMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(vMatrixHandle, 1, false, viewMatrix, 0);
    GLES20.glUniformMatrix4fv(pMatrixHandle, 1, false, projectionMatrix, 0);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually my matrix multiplication order in shader was wrong, the correct order is:

`gl_Position =  u_pMatrix * u_mMatrix * u_vMatrix * a_Position;`

so the correct shader source is:

```
private final String vertexShader =
              "uniform mat4 u_mMatrix;      \n"       // Матрица модели
            + "uniform mat4 u_vMatrix;      \n"       // Матрица модели
            + "uniform mat4 u_pMatrix;      \n"        // Матрица модели

            + "attribute vec4 a_Position;     \n"     // Информация о положении вершин.

            + "attribute vec2 a_TexCoordinate; \n"    // Per-vertex texture coordinate information we will pass in.
            + "varying vec2 v_TexCoordinate;   \n"    // This will be passed into the fragment shader.

            + "void main()                    \n"     // Начало программы вершинного шейдера.
            + "{                              \n"
            + "   v_TexCoordinate = a_TexCoordinate; \n"
            + "   gl_Position =  u_pMatrix * u_mMatrix * u_vMatrix  \n"     // gl_Position специальные переменные используемые для хранения конечного положения.
            + "               * a_Position;   \n"     // Умножаем вершины на матрицу для получения конечного положения
            + "}                              \n";    // в нормированных координатах экрана.
```